# Will Microsoft Edge and Windows 10 support HTA?

Tags: vbscript, hta, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm working on an HTML Application for Windows 8.1, and, as our office soon will use Windows 10, I'm wondering if MS Edge and Windows 10 still support HTA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. However, you can still run legacy HTAs in IE9 mode.  For new development using web technologies, Microsoft is recommending a switch to Windows Store Apps.

Here's [what Microsoft had to say](http://web.archive.org/web/20130925022744/https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785055/hta-application-tag-does-not-work-in-ie10) about HTA support in IE10 and later:

> The Internet Explorer team is increasingly focused on standards compliance, and markup-based behaviors are not part of modern web standards. In IE10 mode support for markup based behaviors has been removed, and this includes hta:application.
>
> In addition, for HTML-based applications the focus for Windows 8 and beyond the team's focus is on Windows Store applications.

<del>I suspect that an HTA would work in Windows 10, but only in IE9 mode.</del> (EDIT: It does!)  It would be a major shift if Microsoft built Edge with HTA support.

Comment: +1 voted up, but, I had to reread the question / answer (including the Microsoft link) a few times. Summing up: HTA work in Windows 10? Yes (but only in IE9 mode). HTA work in Microsoft Edge? No (since that's IE10+ but with HTA support removed).

Comment: I agree, the answer should read: "**Yes**, Windows 10 supports HTA, but it runs in IE9 compatibility mode."

Comment: I respect your disagreement with my answer.  Please don't edit my answer to read "Yes" where I have "No".  Rather, add your own answer (it's not too late).  Feel free to downvote my answer.  I'm sorry that it's confusing to you, but I don't feel that allowing ancient HTAs to continue to work on Win10 is the same thing as "supporting" HTAs.  If Win10 supported HTA, I would be able to code a standards-compliant web app and have it run in a privileged container with file-system access and all the other goodies that HTAs enjoy.  To be stuck in IE9 mode is the very definition of dropping support.

Comment: Windows 10 supports HTA and defaults to IE7 mode, but you can specify the mode all the way up to IE11.

Comment: @Herohtar, when you specify IE11 mode, it ignores the `<HTA:APPLICATION>` element, so you are unable to access the filesystem, etc.  I'm not sure what the point would be without that.  See also: http://web.archive.org/web/20130925022744/https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785055/hta-application-tag-does-not-work-in-ie10

Comment: @gilly That's only partially true; the `<HTA:APPLICATION>` element is ignored, but you can still access the filesystem. It is also possible to semi-workaround the ignored tag by not setting the compatibility and using `NAVIGABLE="yes"`, then navigating to a file that does have the compatibility set to IE11.

Answer (score 3):

Late post but after testing, yes, HTA are fully support by Windows 10 and IE/Edge Browser.  After declaring the doc type (important) at the top of your hta file (), set the meta tag in the head dom-node.  Something like :

- `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />`
- `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=10" />`
- `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11" />`
- `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />`

JScript run on 4 versions, VBS run on 9 and 10.

Please refer to this site for more detail (keyword : compatible) :
-https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_hta.php#Quirks