# HTA apps in Windows 10 phone

Tags: windows-phone, hta, windows-10-mobile

Is HTA supposed to work on Windows 10 phones? It seems like it knows it's supposed to launch it, but something isn't right.

The HTA file that I tried to run, looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test HTA app</title>
    <hta:application id="myApp" 
    applicationname="monster" 
    border="none"
    caption="no"
    showintaskbar="yes"
    singleinstance="yes"
    sysmenu="no"
    windowstate="maximize">
</head>
<body>
    <p>If you can read this, HTA works!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And, before I tried to launch it, I went to Security > For developers, and set the Developer features to "Developer mode" instead of the original option "Windows Store apps".

Then I downloaded the HTA file, clicked on it from my Downloads app, and all I get is a message saying

> LAUNCH FILE
>
> Something went wrong. Could not launch the file.

Is there something I can do to make it work?

And just to avoid possibly having another question later; is Javascript going to work?

Comment: Remember windows 10 default browser is edge which is much more standards based then ie.  Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975195/will-microsoft-edge-and-windows-10-support-hta

Answer (score 1):

No, I believe HTA will not work for Windows Phone 10.

Edge (Windows phone 10's browser) does not support it.

See this link: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785055/hta-application-tag-does-not-work-in-ie10