# HTA Gamepad API (or alternatives)

Tags: hta, launcher, gamepad, gamepad-api

I am building an game launcher app (similar to Steam Big Picture) using HTA and I'd like to be able to control this app using my X360 controller.
One way to do it is to use Xpadder and emulate keyboard presses, but since MS Edge has a native support of Gamepad API, I wonder whether there is a way to enable it for HTA (since for example flexboxes can be enabled for HTA).

Or.. if it's not possible, are there any alternatives for HTA? That means something I can write in HTML5+CSS3+Javascript, have it start in fullscreen and have it launch .bat files on my computer without asking for any permissions?

Comment: I'm not sure the HTA engine in `mshta.exe` runs with the Edge rendering engine it's included for backward compatibility. It's not really changed since IE 9 *(to my knowledge, but don't quote me)*.

Comment: Not sure if it's really an edge rendering engine, but it's at least IE11 rendering engine, since flexboxes do not work in IE9. I use following header:
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30992020/692942) to a [similar-*ish* question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30975195/692942)...

> *I suspect that an HTA would work in Windows 10, but only in IE9 mode. It would be a major shift if Microsoft built Edge with HTA support.*

I would conclude you wouldn't be able to use the Gamepad API in a HTA because it uses the IE 9 rendering engine.

Your best bet is give it a try and test it for yourself.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Can I use Gamepad API?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=gamepad)

Comment: I have tried it. On Windows 10, IE11 do not work with the Gamepad API, Edge does. Using an example Gamepad API application from M$ pages somewhere, gamepad worked for me in edge, but did not work after running it with mshta.exe. I used following header:
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
which probably uses IE11 rendering engine (since IE11 in debug mode has rendering engine set to "Edge" with IE11 nowhere to be found).

That said, are there any alternatives to HTA with an ability to run .bat files on my computer?

Comment: @doomista To be honest I'm not sure what compatibility `mshta.exe` has with compatibility headers / meta values. Either way it is a depreciated technology and trying to use it like this will give you more of a headache then it's worth.

Comment: It's great for writing app launchers which is exactly what I am doing here. And basically the only thing I cannot do right now with HTA is the gamepad driven input. Meta headers do affect behaviour of `mshta.exe` in (as far as I can tell) the same manner as viewing the page with the different renderer using the Developer Tools. And I also understand that it's a deprecated technology. That's why I am asking for alternatives.