# Trouble embedding google drive video into HTA

Tags: embed, hta

I have been working on a project for a few days now and hit a snag. I need to be able to embed a google drive video into an HTA application. I have looked everywhere for an answer and tried things such as the html5 method (which I have discovered is not supported by an hta application):

```
<video id="vid_1" width="720" height="480" autoplay="true">
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRLxDgyDJqKUHViVkVPQlIwUGc/preview" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

the google drive "auto-embed" method:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRLxDgyDJqKUHViVkVPQlIwUGc/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

which came up with these errors and showed a blank screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebsvM.jpg

and finally the good old fashion object/embed method:

```
<object type="video/mp4" data="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRLxDgyDJqKUHViVkVPQlIwUGc/preview" width="340" height="280">
    <param name="src" value="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRLxDgyDJqKUHViVkVPQlIwUGc/preview" />
    <param name="controller" value="true" />
    <param name="autostart" value="true" />
</object>
```

and

```
<embed class="vidPlayer" autostart="true" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRLxDgyDJqKUHViVkVPQlIwUGc/preview" type='video/mp4'/>
```

both of which simply showed a white screen.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I'm beginning to think it is impossible... The widths and lengths are completely optional, those are currently just placeholders in the code. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: According to this question, HTA is apparently stuck in legacy IE code, which Google may not support anymore. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975195/will-microsoft-edge-and-windows-10-support-hta You might consider some of the available alternatives for packaging web applications as desktop applications.

Comment: Do you know of any specific alternatives for HTA?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10"/>
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

inside the  tag your HTA as without this it will run as if you are using IE6 even if you have the latest version of explorer installed.

Try adding it and then you should be able to get the  tag working.

Note that newer versions of IE do not support VB script so adding this line may prevent VB script from running.  You can either use Javascript instead or specify IE9.